# I need to change the Read Only in gedit to Read/Write

Tags: gedit

I am BRAND new to Ubuntu.

I just installed it along with Win7 as dual-boot.  I need to edit the grub file and reset the grub-timeout from 10 to 0.  I have done this from the terminal with

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

I then entered my password and got the `gedit` screen with the grub file on it.  I then changed the timeout from 10 to 0.  Now I find that gedit is marked as [Read-Only].

How can I save my file?

Comment: run with `gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub`. you may need to install `sudo apt-get install gksu` first if you get error "not installed gksudo"

Comment: Hi & welcome to **AU**. Try `gksudo` instead of `sudo`. It is the most efficient way of using the editor.

Answer (score 2):

To edit configuration files, I would always use in your place a text-based editor:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Answer (score 1):

`gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub` *is indeed the **correct** answer to your question*, **however**, if you're *brand new* to Ubuntu, I'd advise you to install [Grub Customiser](https://launchpad.net/~danielrichter2007/+archive/ubuntu/grub-customizer).

Grub Customiser allows you to change a ton of parameters in grub without the risk of you making a fatal mistake. ;-) (Fatal to Ubuntu, not to you!)

In a terminal type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

and then in the dash type: "Grub Cu" to open it…